# Selecting month in each year with maximum number of projects

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following scenario

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjjuU.png)

For each year I would like to display the month with the highest number of projects that have ended

I have tried the following so far:

```
SELECT  COUNT(proj.projno) nr_proj, extract(month from proj.end_date) month
, extract(year from proj.end_date) year
 FROM PROJ
 GROUP BY extract(month from proj.end_date)
             ,extract(year from proj.end_date)
```

I am getting the information about the number of projects per month, per year.
Could any one give me hints how for each of the years I would select only the records with the highest count of projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution using ***max analytic function*** to get max nr_proj value per year (partition by clause), then keep only rows where nr_proj = mx.

```sql
select t.nr_proj, t.month, t.year
from (
SELECT COUNT(proj.projno) nr_proj
    , extract(month from proj.end_date) month
    , extract(year from proj.end_date) year
    , max( COUNT(proj.projno) ) over(partition by extract(year from proj.end_date)) mx
FROM PROJ 
GROUP BY extract(month from proj.end_date), extract(year from proj.end_date)
) t
where nr_proj = mx
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c64ed170921c444789fd753da0d3eff)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will give you what you are after (if I understood the requirements). It fist counts the projects for each month then ranks the months by year, finally it selects the first rank.

```
select dt "Most Projects Month", cnt "Monthly Projects"
  from ( -- Rank month Count by Year 
         select to_char( dt, 'yyyy-mm') dt
           , cnt 
           , rank() over (partition by extract(year from dt) 
                              order by cnt desc) rnk
        from (-- count number of in month projects for each year         
              select trunc(end_date,'mon') dt, count(*) cnt
                from projects
               group by trunc(end_date,'mon') 
              )
      )
where rnk = 1
order by dt;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, no data supplied.  In future do not post images, see [Why No Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).